# Argument 2 passed to Dingo\Api\Auth\Provider\JWT::authenticate() must be an instance of Dingo\Api\Routing\Route

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5.5, dingo-api

I'm using [dingo/api](https://github.com/dingo/api) along with [nWidart/laravel-modules](https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules) packages to create an API.

We know that in **nwidart** package each Module can it's model and service provider.

Now suppose we have a `PriceList` model like this :

```
class PriceList extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'price_list_id';

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'name', 'country', 'rate', 'creator'];

    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        $attributes['creator'] = app('Dingo\Api\Auth\Auth')->user()->user_id;
        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }
}
```

Then in the `PriceListServiceProvider` of that module, for some reason , I need to fetch a specific `price list` and store `id` of that in config. For that I wrote these:

```
class PriceListServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $defer = FALSE;

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerTranslations();
        $this->registerConfig();
        $this->registerViews();
        $this->registerFactories();
        $this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__ . '/../Database/Migrations');

        $priceList =
            PriceList::where('rate', 'toman')->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->first();

        if ($priceList) {
            $defaultPriceList = $priceList->price_list_id;
        }

        config('pricelist.default',$defaultPriceList);

    }

}
```

But after running project I got this error every time :

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Type error: Argument 2 passed to Dingo\Api\Auth\Provider\JWT::authenticate() must be an instance of Dingo\Api\Routing\Route, null given, called in D:\wamp\www\zarsam-app\vendor\dingo\api\src\Auth\Auth.php on line 82 in file D:\wamp\www\zarsam-app\vendor\dingo\api\src\Auth\Provider\JWT.php on line 41
Stack trace:
  1. Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError-&gt;() D:\wamp\www\zarsam-app\vendor\dingo\api\src\Auth\Provider\JWT.php:41
  2. Dingo\Api\Auth\Provider\JWT-&gt;authenticate() D:\wamp\www\zarsam-app\vendor\dingo\api\src\Auth\Auth.php:82
  3. Dingo\Api\Auth\Auth-&gt;authenticate() D:\wamp\www\zarsam-app\vendor\dingo\api\src\Auth\Auth.php:151
  4. Dingo\Api\Auth\Auth-&gt;getUser() D:\wamp\www\zarsam-app\vendor\dingo\api\src\Auth\Auth.php:166
  5. Dingo\Api\Auth\Auth-&gt;user() D:\wamp\www\zarsam-app\Modules\PriceList\Entities\PriceList.php:18
  6. Modules\PriceList\Entities\PriceList-&gt;__construct() D:\wamp\www\zarsam-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php:1450
  7. Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model-&gt;__callStatic() D:\wamp\www\zarsam-app\app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php:37
  8. App\Providers\AppServiceProvider-&gt;boot() D:\wamp\www\zarsam-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:29
  9. call_user_func_array() D:\wamp\www\zarsam-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:29
 10. Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod-&gt;Illuminate\Container\{closure}() D:\wamp\www\zarsam-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:87
 11. Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod-&gt;callBoundMethod() D:\wamp\www\zarsam-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:31
 12. Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod-&gt;call() D:\wamp\www\zarsam-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:549
 13. Illuminate\Container\Container-&gt;call() D:\wamp\www\zarsam-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:792
 14. Illuminate\Foundation\Application-&gt;bootProvider() D:\wamp\www\zarsam-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:775
 15. Illuminate\Foundation\Application-&gt;Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}() [internal]:0
 16. array_walk() D:\wamp\www\zarsam-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:776
 17. Illuminate\Foundation\Application-&gt;boot() D:\wamp\www\zarsam-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders.php:17
 18. Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders-&gt;bootstrap() D:\wamp\www\zarsam-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:213
 19. Illuminate\Foundation\Application-&gt;bootstrapWith() D:\wamp\www\zarsam-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:162
 20. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;bootstrap() D:\wamp\www\zarsam-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:146
 21. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;sendRequestThroughRouter() D:\wamp\www\zarsam-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:116
 22. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;handle() D:\wamp\www\zarsam-app\public\index.php:55
```

And if I remove those lines, no errors occurred.

Even I moved codes to main `AppServiceProvider` but same error again occurred.

Comment: Do you have any user authenticated ? `app('Dingo\Api\Auth\Auth')->user()->user_id;`

Comment: yes surely, as I said when I remove that piece of code that fetch `PriceList::where('rate', 'toman')->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->first()` codes , all things worked fine

Comment: so the query returns null

Comment: Even I use `$priceList = PriceList::all()` that I sure is not empty, that returns same error.